# SUMIF from a table that only shows filtered data

Tags: excel-formula, sumifs

```
=subtotal(9,sumif(table1[product],E6,table1[quantity]))
```

Please can you show me how I amend this so that it changes based on the filter?

Thanks

Comment: What version do you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT like this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(table1[quantity],BYROW(table1[product],LAMBDA(a,subtotal(3,a)))*(table1[product]=E6))
```

this basically tests if the row is visible or not and the `product` equals `E6`.  If both are TRUE, then it will pass the quantity value to the SUMPRODUCT, otherwise it will pass `0`.

`BYROW(table1[product],LAMBDA(a,subtotal(3,a)))` creates an array of 1 and 0 based on if the row is visible or not.